# How to choose variable names for parallel computing?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am using the `foreach` package for parallel computing. In the loop I have defined temporary variables with fixed names (like "temp") that will be overwritten in the next iteration because that's how I usually do it in classic loops. Now I am wondering if this is possible using parallel computing or if there will be a mix up in the variables when doing parallel computation.

Basically, the underlying question is if the temporary variables are given a "local" (with respect to the iteration) temporary names or not. Does the program detect which variables have the same names throughout the iterations to give them this "local" temporary name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'foreach' follow the same logic of 'for' in this aspect. The temporary objects will not be in the global environment. Take a look in the example below.

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

cores <- 2
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

# data
n <- 4
m <- lapply(1:n, function(i) matrix((1:4), 2, 2))
rnames <- c("r1", "r2")

x <- foreach (i = 1:n) %dopar% {
temp <- m[[i]] * i 
temp <- as.data.frame(temp)
data.frame(r = rnames, temp)
}
x # each new matrix are in the correct order in the output list
temp # it exist only inside the foreach

stopCluster(cl)
```